# Cannot get custom font to work in Corona

Tags: windows, ipad, fonts, lua, coronasdk

I've read the tutorials and related questions here but still no luck using a custom font.

I'm on a Windows 7 machine and I've performed the following steps:

- Installed the Font (Print Clearly OT.otf)
- Copied the otf file to the project directory (same directory as the main.lua)
- Restarted the Corona simulator
- Used this code to find the font name (Print Clearly OT) and add the build settings: http://coronalabs.com/blog/2013/01/16/faq-wednesday-custom-fonts/

Trying to use the font like:

```
lettertext = display.newText( "a", 40, 20, "Print Clearly OT", 24 )
```

Start up the simulator for ipad and I get "could not load font" message.

There was a comment on the link tutorial above, about otf files not working on windows but i assumed that was on a windows mobile device not in the ipad simulator on a windows system.

Answer (score 0):

OTF fonts are not supported in Windows (like you can read at the [link](http://coronalabs.com/blog/2013/01/16/faq-wednesday-custom-fonts/) you provided) but you could use a ttf version of "Print Clearly OT" font, ttf fonts are supported in all systems.

The other solution is develop with a mac machine, Corona simulator will work better in this case but this solution is really expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Corona SDK also uses the "Internal Font Name".  The internal name could be different than the file name and the display name.  It might be PrintClearly-Regular or something like that.

But likely it's the OTF's don't work on Windows.